# Document management system for Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, document-management

I am developing a intranet portal for the company.I need to intergrate a document management system for that. Back-end Spring RestApi and front-end in Angular 6. IS there any open source document management systems already build using Angular ?

Comment: Did you find such component ?